# JQuery UI Dialog autoResize not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-dialog, autoresize

I'm having an issue with the JQuery dialog autoResize option. I use the dialog to show an AJAX call result, so i can't predict the final height of the dialog. I'd like itself adjust its height to its content size. I read over there about the `autoResize` option, but seems to not work properly.

Here my code:

```
    $("#my_dialog").dialog({
        modal:true,
        autoResize: true,
        open:function(){
            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-widget-header")
            .removeClass("ui-widget-header").addClass("ui-widget-header-ia");
        }
    });
```

but when the AJAX content is loaded, the size of the Dialog does not change, and an scrollbar appears instead.

The issue is that testing this same code, without the `autoResize`option in IE6 works fine!!

So i'm thinking maybe is because of Google Chrome does not support this option.

Can you help me please? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem- One user had always the dialog opened as too low and the height wasn't updated even if the content was updated. I couldn't reproduce the problem at first, tried with several versions, OS's etc. Then I stumbled upon this:

http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2010/10/chrome-and-jquery-ui-min-height-issue.html

It seems that the zoom level caused the issue, at least in my case. If I loaded the original page with default zoom (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> in Chrome), the dialog opens ok. Then I closed the dialog, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (Chrome zooms out), reloaded the page with <kbd>F5</kbd>, reopened the dialog and the problem occurred every time. Reloading seems mandatory, if I loaded the original page with the default zoom and zoomed out then, the dialogs knew their heights. Apparently the min-height capability check described in link is run when loading the original page.

I haven't yet figured out a workaround other than not to zoom out, but that might be the cause of your problem too.

Comment: is exactly what is happening to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I found that **jQuery UI explicitly sets the element's height** when creating / opening the dialog. Therefore a useful workaround is to simply reset the element's css height attribute **after** opening like so:

```
  element.dialog('open');
  element.css('height', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If we don't know how much content we are going to display better to use [resizable option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-resizable) for the jquery ui modla dialog.You can as well try out the [autoresize plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)

Comment: no resizable option or autoresize plugin working :(, it seems to ignore the options `autoResize` and `resizable`

Comment: in the jquery doc page, its said that `resizable` option's default value is true, so is the same that do not include it in the initialization of the dialog